# Adding websockets to MVC ASP.NET C# Application

Tags: c#, postgresql, model-view-controller, websocket

I have a MVC Web Application with connection to Postgresql with Heroku.
It display/edit/delete data from the database.

I have to add Websockets or socket.io (I've read about SignalIR, should be good?) to handle messages between the clients and the server.

I dont have `Startup.cs` class.

I have read a lot of implementations but I dont know where to place them, should I make some class and just implement the methods? And where to place it afterwards? Any tutorials would be awesome but I dont know how to put it in place.

Global.asax

```cs
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}
```

I would very much appreciate help.

Comment: Are you willing to use signalr? It is perfect for a scenario like this and is built into .net core. It is really easy to setup different hubs and use them in your controllers.

Comment: Yes but whenever i see a tutorial, someone has Startup.cs file in his project and I dont, its similar to Global.asax

Answer (score 0):

If you are missing a startup.cs file, create one in the root of your folder. Something like this ->

```
public class Startup
{
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){
      services.AddSignalR();
   }

   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
       app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapHub<examplehub>("/examplehub");
        });
    }
}
```

Something like this might get you started on the right path.

And an example hub could look something like this

```
public class examplehub: Hub
{
    public async Task examplehubendpoint(int UserId)
    {
        await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, $"/User/{UserId}");
    }
}
```

If you aren't using .netcore, your  Global.asax  will look different. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/older-versions/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc-4)
Something like this:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();      
}
```

The hub functions will look slightly different too as everything is not async

```
public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        // Call the addNewMessageToPage method to update clients.
        Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage(name, message);
    }
```

Comment: I have error with IServiceCollection, should i install Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjectionAbstractions like it tells me to?

Comment: Are you using .net core?

Comment: If you aren't using .net core, I suggest taking a look at this article for signalr.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/older-versions/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc-4

Comment: The SignalR hub will look similar, however your global.asxc will look different  Global.asax

Comment: I wouldn't since you are not using .net core, I updated my answer , add     RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();      
 to the top, this will cover what startup is doing, then create your hub. Look at the bottom of my answer

Comment: How do I have to modify my .html file and what .js script should I use, cause I tried using one and it cant make connectio. I have created Startup.cs file because in another post some1 said to do this because i had an exception

Comment: You can use the signalr js package to listen to the hubs

Comment: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-JS-Client